# why taefik could not proxy to the kubernetes pod service

Tags: kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I want to using taefik(v2.0) to proxy service into kubernetes(v1.15.2) cluster pod,this is my taefik config:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: fat-api-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`k8s-fat-api.example.com`) 
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: soa-red-envelope-service
          port: 11005
```

and I login taefik management dashboard and find this error:

```
the service "dabai-fat-fat-api-route-789d6ee4fcf7288b0f7f@kubernetescrd" does not exist
```

I am sure the `soa-red-envelope-service` pod start success and listening on port 11005.When I change the backend service to eureka and eureka port and it works fine. It says the config is ok, the pod is ok, now where is the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either don't have a kubernetes service with name `soa-red-envelope-service` pointing to the backend pods or you have the service but not in the namespace where you have created the ingressroute.